# Cannot access Yahoo Mail

Tags: email, login

My wife's Yahoo mail account is acting weird.

She can login to Yahoo and change account settings, etc: `login.yahoo.com`. We've changed her password.

Weirdly, she cannot access yahoo mail: `mail.yahoo.com`.

Basically, we enter her user ID and password and the login just reappears (loops).

Comment: Trying deleting all `*.yahoo.com` cookies.

Comment: It'd help if you told us your operating system and browser as well.

Comment: Try deleting browser cache & cookies. If you don't know how, Google has instructions for all major browsers:  http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32050

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably cookies. Try deleting the cookies associated with yahoo.com. @bytesum gives a good comment to your original question, with [Google's descriptions of how different browsers handle cookie management](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en).

Easy ways to tell if this is likely to work? Go to a different computer (previously unused by your wife and not known itself to have any problems logging into yahoo) and try there; or use a different web browser on the same machine and see if that works.

Answer (score -3):

Try using another browser.... Firefox seems to be the best, especially beefed up with EFF plugin to have end-to-end SSL, namely keeping network-sniffing malware away from your passwords, or even better - all your mails.

Comment: You don't even know what browser the OP has.

Comment: If you plan to salvage this answer by saying that using the [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) add-on will solve the problem, please elaborate. Currently, this post is just a passing comment...

Comment: "Try another browser" doesn't depend on the original